# How to make status bar tapped programmatically when view appeared?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Does anybody know is there any way to call status bar tapping programmatically when view appeared? My view is not on the top when appearing.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: if you have some action that happens when user taps status bar - why not to call it from viewWillAppear method of your ViewController?

Comment: Sime my table views aren't loading correctly. Some table view are appearing on top and some on middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that what you want to do is scroll your view to the top, which is what tapping the status bar does. If that's the case then here is a nice little view controller extension to achieve that.

```
extension UIViewController {
   func scrollToTop() {
       func scrollToTop(view: UIView?) {
           guard let view = view else { return }
           switch view {
           case let scrollView as UIScrollView:
              if scrollView.scrollsToTop == true {
                 scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
                 return
              }
           default:
              break
           }

           for subView in view.subviews {
              scrollToTop(view: subView)
           }
        }

        scrollToTop(view: view)
     }

     var isScrolledToTop: Bool {
        for subView in view.subviews {
           if let scrollView = subView as? UIScrollView {
              return (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
           }
        }
        return true
      }
  }
```

Then in the `viewDidAppear` of your view controller, you can call

`myViewController.scrollToTop()`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Comment: Not working with iPhone XR, iOS 13 (scrolling to the middle instead of top).